# How can I create an average length of time in from multiple dates / times?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, forex

I am trying to calculate the average length of trades from a number of trades.

B10 thru B20 - are my entry dates and times formatted like 07/14/2014 04:00.

M10 thru M20 - are my exits dates and times formatted like 07/17/2014 08:00.

O10 thru O20 - are my lengths of trade which display as "3 Days 4 Hr 0 Min" using the following calculation =IF(M10="","",INT(M10-B10)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(M10-B10,1))&" Hr "&MINUTE(MOD(M10-B10,1))&" Min")

I am having difficulties in combining the average of the 20 trades from O10 thru O20.  I believe it is because of the above calculation format, but I do not know how to overcome this.

Anyone have any recommendations/suggestions as to how I can properly calculate the average length of time that I am in a trade over these last 20 trades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, it's difficult to calculate the average from column O because those are text strings, you can simply use the average of the entry timestamps subtracted from the average of the exit timestamps, e.g.

`=AVERAGE(M10:M20)-AVERAGE(B10:B20)`

or to get formatted as per the column O format

`=INT(AVERAGE(M10:M20)-AVERAGE(B10:B20))&" Days "&TEXT(AVERAGE(M10:M20)-AVERAGE(B10:B20),"h"" Hr ""m"" Min""")`

btw you could use this simplified formula along the same lines to get your column O text string

`=IF(M10="","",INT(M10-B10)&" Days "&TEXT(M10-B10,"h"" Hr ""m"" Min"""))`

Comment: @barry_houdini... thanks so much.  Let me give this a try and see if I can get this to work properly.  Thanks for the time and help once again!

Comment: This is a wonderful help.  I have only ran into one issue that I would like to ask you about.   This is a spreadsheet of multiple trades that I use.  It tracks the last 100 trades.  I have only entered 11 to this point (M10:M20).  The calculation works great for those already entered.  Is there a way to include the entire set (M10 thru M110)?  Right now when I include the entire data set... the return comes back invalid because some fields are still blank.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It should work as long as some rows have entries, blank rows will be ignored by AVERAGE function, did you change all ranges to the same size?

Comment: Barry... I am an idiot.  That was it!!   Feel foolish.  Thanks again for the help along the way!   Thanks for the answer and hopefully this question / answer may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Create an alternative column `P` where you put the **actual value** of the lengths:

```
= M10 - B10
```

Average (Say it's `P21`):

```
= Average(P10:P20)
```

This value will be in days.

You can then take the hours (`P22`):

```
= (P21 - int(P21)) * 24
```

And the minutes:

```
= (P22 - int(P22)) * 60
```

And you can manage to mend all those formulas in a single one for your formatting

Comment: Daniel... do you know of a way that I wouldn't have to create a separate column for this?

Comment: I am working to this end now, but not sure how to "mend" these different components into a Days / Hours / Minute.

Comment: when I start with the initial calculation of m10-b10 the return is 1/3/1900 0:00.  How should I properly format this to work in the future calculation?